# Distinguish between single and doubleclick

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following snippet for distinguishing between clicks and doubleclicks:

```
observeSingleAndDoubleClick: function (element, singleClickHandler, doubleClickHandler, timeout) {
    var clicks;
    $(element).observe('click', function (event) {
        ++clicks;
        if (clicks === 1) {
            var timeoutCallback = function (event) {
                if (clicks === 1) {
                    singleClickHandler.call(this, event);
                } else {
                    doubleClickHandler.call(this, event);
                }
                clicks = 0;
            };
            timeoutCallback.bind(this).delay(timeout / 1000);
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Problem: The event does not live anymore when the delay callback gets called. Though it works in Firefox but it does not in IE8. The event object passed to the click handlers is "dead" since the event itself is already passed.

Anyone has an advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: I wouldn't do this at all, frankly. The reliability of browser timers is so low that you're going to drive users crazy.  The web just doesn't do double-click in general.

Comment: Why not use onclick and ondblclick?  is it an object that does not support it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.ondblclick

Comment: @mplungian even with that approach it's necessary to add some sort of timer code. Why?  Because every "dblclick" will *also* fire a "click" event first.  Thus, your "click" event handler has to wait to see if a "dblclick" also happens.  It's a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the OpenLayers project foes something similar. Look at line 210 in this file: [OpenLayers.Handler.Click sourcecode](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Handler/Click.js).

I don't know how to use this with the Prototype framework, but I hope it can get you on the right way :)

Another thing: wouldn't it better to use the mouseUp event instead of the click?

Answer (score 3):

Don't only observe the click event but also the doubleclick event.

```
$(element).observe('click',singleClickHandler); 
$(element).observe('dblclick',doubleClickHandler);
```

Here is a changed version after all the discussion:

```
var clicks;    
observeSingleAndDoubleClick: function (element, singleClickHandler, doubleClickHandler, timeout) {

$(element).observe('click', function (event) {
    ++clicks;
    if (clicks === 1) {
        var timeoutCallback = function (event) {
            if (clicks === 1) {
                singleClickHandler.call(this, event);
            } else {
                doubleClickHandler.call(this, event);
            }
            clicks = 0;
        };
        timeoutCallback.bind(this, event).delay(timeout / 1000);
    }
}.bind(this));
```

}

Comment: This is very unlikely to work reliably, if at all. [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#dblclick) is a brief paragraph from QuirksMode for example.

Comment: @Pointy That's not true. 'dblclick' is used in prototypejs very often and works in all browsers. Give me concrete examples of inconsistent behavior or don't comment at all

Comment: It's not that "dblclick" is bad, it's bad *in conjunction* with "click" *on the same element*.

Comment: singleClickHandler will get triggered on the first click auf the doubleclick wouldnt it? thats exactly my problem

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the explanation and you are right. Point taken

Comment: @Benjamin. Taken the advice of Pointy in mind your own solution looks like a nice one... Yes it is messy but like Pointy pointed out it will be messy. Define the variable clicks outside the scope of the function. In that case it will be available in the timeoutCallBack

Comment: ok now I understand. Then, I would not do it. Add another button or link instead.

Comment: @TurBas. Well the problem is, the event does not exist anymore when I am in the timeout callback. But I want to read out data from it.

Comment: @Benjamin That is because in this line 'timeoutCallback.bind(this).delay(timeout / 1000);' you don't pass the event in. Send the event in it: 'timeoutCallback.bind(this, event).delay(timeout / 1000);' or use 'bindAsEventListener'

Comment: even that won't work, try it out yourself in IE8 if you want ;-)
the event is not valid anymore in the timeout callback since it's life ends with it's observer

Comment: @Benjamin Create another object and put the values of the event you need in that object. Pass that object in with your function.

Comment: @TurBas. Any way to do this in a generic way? Simply cloning the event object does not work...

Comment: @Benjamin Which items of the event object do you need? Or is it different in each case? Else you should do something like: 'var newEvent = {}; newEvent.prop1 = event.prop1;'

Comment: @TurBas: Thanks, maybe that's the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `dblclick` event id on Prototype. Why don't you use it?

```
observeSingleAndDoubleClick: function (element, singleClickHandler, doubleClickHandler) {

  $(element).observe('click', function (event) {
    singleClickHandler.call(this, event);
  }

  $(element).observe('dblclick', function (event) {
    doubleClickHandler.call(this, event);
  }
}
```

Comment: because singleClickHandler will get triggered on the first click auf the doubleclick

Comment: In that case, add another button or link. If you are doing different things on click and doubleclick you are just asking for trouble.